# TimeField returning None in Django

Tags: django

I have an existing database I need to pull data from the timestamp field in Django. I created the Django model as a TimeField, but when I query the data I get 'None' instead of the data in the timestamp field.

From my model class: (there is more in the model, I just condensed this for readability)

```js
class Report(models.Model):
  upload_time = models.TimeField()
  date = models.CharField(max_length=9)
  
  @staticmethod
  def get_reports(**query):
    reports = Report.objects.order_by('date').filter(query)
    for report in reports:
      print(report.upload_time)
```

In my views.py I have a method that checks for the date I am looking for to pull all reports from that date. The database saved the date as a string, so I get that ok, then just turn it into a datetime object and call my get_reports method by passing the date into it. It works to get everything from the report except the timestamp.

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't `upload_time` be a `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`?

Comment: Williem Van Onsem, I don't know? I can't modify anything in the database. I'm only reading existing data that was created as "timestamp". I don't know how this translates to Django's model class. Right now I'm trying to work around it by bringing it in as a string and then converting it to a datetime object once I've queried the database, but it's not very pretty.